# No support for custom shapped windows in gtk3?

Tags: gtk3, cairo, gtk2

I want to use a custom shaped window using gtk3. I found `gtk_widget_shape_combine_mask_()` [in gtk2](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-shape-combine-mask). The closest thing I can find [in gtk3](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-shape-combine-region) is `gdk_window_shape_combine_region_()`, which only allows for rectangular shaped regions. Why was the support dropped? Or was it changed and implemented in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "why was the support dropped?".

`gtk_widget_shape_combine_mask()` only supports rectangular shapes, too. That's what a `GdkBitmap` is: An image with a bit depth of 1. This means that a pixel is either included or not.

This is basically the same as a `cairo_region_t`. The difference is only in how the data is stored: Instead of a bitmap, `cairo_region_t` uses a list of rectangles to describe the same result.

"Or was it changed and implemented in a different way?"

Yes and you already found the replacement yourself.